# How Can I Identify the Blockchain Where a Smart Contract Is Deployed Using Its Address?

Tags: solidity, web3js, ethers.js, nonce, create

I am trying to identify the specific blockchain where a smart contract has been deployed using its deployment address. However, I am unable to find a clear source or method for doing so.

When I looked up the address-associated transactions using blockchain explorers, I found them listed on three different blockchains: Etherscan, Polygon Test Explorer, and BNB Testnet Explorer. This is confusing, as I expected the contract to be deployed on one specific blockchain.

Can anyone guide me on how to accurately determine the blockchain where the smart contract has been deployed?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't quite understand what you're asking. You have a contract address, but what exactly do you want to find? Source code for a contract or something else?

Comment: What does "determine a deployed smart contract" mean ?

Comment: I wanted to ask that How do I figure out the blockchain associated with a deployed smart contract using its deployment address?
Let me share an example:
I have address of deployed smart contract. Now, how can I determine in which blockchain it's deployed on, such as Ethereum, Polygon, Solana, etc.?

Answer (score 3):

If the question is, can I determine which single chain a contract is deployed on by using its address?

The answer is you can't because it isn't unique.
There isn't a 1-1 mapping of contract address -> chain, so you can't determine it.

The address is deterministic, so deploying from your address with nonce 1 on ethereum will give the same contract address as deploying on arbitrum with a nonce of 1, regardless of the bytecode.

Additionally a block explorer saying that an address is on another chain doesn't mean the address has a contract there, simply that it is a tracked address on another network.

If wanting to knows all chains to which a given address has deployed a given contract to and at what nonce, then you would need to consume and parse their transactions on each chain, like the explorers.

If looking for clones of the contract you would want to match for bytecode regardless of sender.

If looking for deployment addresses, and how they vary across chains, the best bet will be the documentation or github of a given project.

Comment: If the question is, can I determine which single chain a contract is deployed on by using its address?  YES,
If I deployed a smart contract on polygon that will show trasanction of dpeloyed on polygon explorer only, not on other chains explorer I test it right now, I didn't find transaction record on arbiscan and etherscan.

Comment: Perhaps in that one case, but then deploy the same contract on another chain at the same nonce, as you will see with many routers and dapp contracts. Suddenly that "strategy" is useless.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tenderly for searching. It will give you a list of addresses where the address has been created. It will also tell you whether that address is a smart contract or a wallet.

Hope this helps